# Batch nested for loops returns incorrect value

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, nested-loops

problem in my script is return values when indexing files of directory.
In first for I need to loop my array and second for looking for file in directory. Return value is still without change and shows latest value in all variables.
Yes I know, it maybe because I use **setx** but with **set** only it doesn't work absolutely.

```
for /L %%G in (1,1,%i%) do (
  if NOT {arch}=={32} (
    setx DriverPath !DefaultPath!driver\!DriverPath64[%%G]! >nul 2>&1
  ) else (
    setx DriverPath !DefaultPath!driver\!DriverPath32[%%G]! >nul 2>&1
  )

  :: looking for inf file
  for /r "%DriverPath%\" %%f in (*.inf) do (
    set PrinterDriverInf[%%G]=%%f
  )
)
```

Comment: Do you mean `%arch%` in the `if NOT` statement?(the string `arch` does not equals to the string `32`) Did you add `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion before the `for` loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why are you using `setx`? Is the normal `set` command not sufficient? Note that `setx` does not change variables for the current `cmd` instance.
2. The `if not` statement will always evaluate to True, because you have stated literal strings on either side of the `==`. Do you mean `%arch%` instead of `arch`?
3. You'd need delayed expansion for `!DriverPath!`. However, `for /R` cannot use delayedly expanded variables, so you must move the `for /R` loop into a sub-routine to be able to use immediate `%`-expansion, or you change to the directory temporarily and let `for /R` default to that (changed) current directory.
4. Never use `::` comments in parenthesised blocks, use `rem` instead.

Here is the fixed code:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%G in (1,1,%i%) do (
    if not "%arch%"=="32" (
        setx DriverPath !DefaultPath!driver\!DriverPath64[%%G]! >nul 2>&1
        set "DriverPath=!DefaultPath!driver\!DriverPath64[%%G]!"
    ) else (
        setx DriverPath !DefaultPath!driver\!DriverPath32[%%G]! >nul 2>&1
        set "DriverPath=!DefaultPath!driver\!DriverPath32[%%G]!"
    )
    rem looking for inf file
    call :SUB PrinterDriverInf[%%G] "%DriverPath%"
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:SUB    
    for /R "%~2" %%f in (*.inf) do (
        set "%~1=%%f"
    )
    goto :EOF
```

You could even simplify the code like this:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not "%arch%"=="32" set "arch=64"
for /L %%G in (1,1,%i%) do (
    setx DriverPath !DefaultPath!driver\!DriverPath%arch%[%%G]! >nul 2>&1
    set "DriverPath=!DefaultPath!driver\!DriverPath%arch%[%%G]!"
    rem looking for inf file
    pushd "!DriverPath!" && (
        for /R %%f in (*.inf) do (
            set "PrinterDriverInf[%%G]=%%f"
        )
        popd
    )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `::` comment to a conventional `rem` comment.

`::` is actually a broken label and labels (broken or otherwise) cause problems with code blocks (parenthesised statement sequences)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing(I guess) is that your trying to compare the string `{arch}` and `{32}`.

This is what the command parser see:

> `if the string {arch} equals {32}, do something`

And I guess you want this:

> `if the content of arch variable equals 32, do something`

If so, this would be the command for you.

```
if "%arch%"=="32" echo your commands here
```

Always use quotes `"` instead of `{` and `}` as they are safer.

Comment: oh yes, I forget on %% but this is no problem

Comment: The `%arch%` and `arch` is two different thing.